# Search by Special Character using ElasticSearch

Tags: vb.net, elasticsearch, special-characters, query-string, elasticsearch-query

I am using `ElasticSearch` in my `VB.NET` project. The normal search is working fine i.e. by any word. But, now based on the requirement, I also want to search by special character i.e. `?`. I am using `?` as a normal search but it is not working correctly.
**Code:**

```
client.CreateIndex(Function(d) d.Analysis(Function(z) z.Analyzers(Function(a) a.Add("nGram_analyzer", Get_nGram_analyzer()).
Add("whitespace_analyzer", Get_whitespace_analyzer()).
Add("autocmp", New Nest.CustomAnalyzer() With {.Tokenizer = "edgeNGram", .Filter = {"lowercase"}})).
Tokenizers(Function(t) t.Add("edgeNGram", New Nest.EdgeNGramTokenizer With {.MinGram = 1, .MaxGram = 20})).
TokenFilters(Function(t) t.Add("nGram_filter", Get_nGram_filter()))).
Index(Of view_Article).AddMapping(Of view_Article)(ArticleMapping)

Private Shared Function Get_nGram_filter() As NgramFilter

        Return New NgramFilter With {
            .MinGram = 1,
            .MaxGram = 20,
            .token_chars = New List(Of String) From {"letter", "digit", "punctuation", "symbol"}
        }
End Function

Private Shared Function Get_nGram_analyzer() As CustomAnalyzer
        Return New CustomAnalyzer() With {
            .Tokenizer = "whitespace",
            .Filter = New List(Of String)() From {"lowercase", "asciifolding", "nGram_filter"}
        }
End Function

Private Shared Function Get_whitespace_analyzer() As CustomAnalyzer
        Return New CustomAnalyzer() With {
            .Tokenizer = "whitespace",
            .Filter = New List(Of String)() From {"lowercase", "asciifolding"}
        }
End Function
```

**Search Query:**

```
"query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "\\?",
      "fields": [
        "title"
      ],
      "default_operator": "and",
      "analyze_wildcard": true
    }
  }
```

**Note:** I want to search it in many ways. i.e. keyword, keyword + special character, or just special character.

Comment: Did you try escaping the question mark? As it is an elasticsearch wildcard you will need to prep end it with a slash "\?" I believe. Oh, and the code above is VB.NET not C#

Comment: @SimonWilson My bad. Yes, it is `VB.NET`. I tried it with a slash `"\"?\""` but it returns 0 records. If I use `"\?"` then it returns SearchParseException.

Comment: @JeetenParmar, you need to escape properly using `\\?` in JSON, I am not familiar with vb.net syntax, but you can easily check this, also pls refer the JSON sample which I posted.

Comment: @JeetenParmar, also please use the `_analyze` api to confirm these special chars are present in your generated tokens.

Comment: @JeetenParmar, were u able to resolve the issue?

Comment: @OpsterElasticsearchNinja No, It didn't solve my problem. Please see my updated question, I have included `_analyze` api.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing my answer based on the dicussion with @jeeten, also answer given by @Nishant would work but has following functional and non-functional issues:

**Functional issue:**

1. Only `?` and `/` special characters are allowed in the search while using that it would allow search on all the punctuations.

**Non-functional issues:**

2. This would cause 3 fields to index in a different format, which would increase the index-size on disk, also puts more pressure on memory as Elasticsearch caches the inverted index for better search performance.
3. Again, searching requires all the three different fields to search, and searching in more fields again causes performance issues.
4. tokens are duplicated in three fields of the `title` field.

### My solution

To address the above functional and non-functional requirements, I used `[pattern_capture][1]` token-filter to index only `?` and `/`, it also uses `"preserve_original": true,` to support searches like `foo?`.

**I am also indexing 2 fields and searching only on two fields to improve the performance.**

### Index def

```
{
    "settings": {
        "analysis": {
            "filter": {
                "splcharfilter": {
                    "type": "pattern_capture",
                    "preserve_original": true,
                    "patterns": [
                        "([?/])" --> extendable for future requirments.
                    ]
                }
            },
            "analyzer": {
                "splcharanalyzer": {
                    "tokenizer": "keyword",
                    "filter": [
                        "splcharfilter",
                        "lowercase"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "title": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                    "splchar": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "analyzer": "splcharanalyzer"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Search query

```
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "\\?", --> change this according to queries.
      "fields": ["title", "title.splchar"] --> noyte only 2 fields
    }
  }
}
```

### Search result

```
"hits": [
            {
                "_index": "pattern-capture",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "2",
                "_score": 1.0341108,
                "_source": {
                    "title": "Are you ready to change the climate?"
                }
            },
            {
                "_index": "pattern-capture",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "4",
                "_score": 1.0341108,
                "_source": {
                    "title": "What are the effects of direct public transfers on social solidarity?"
                }
            }
        ]
```

P.S:- Not mentioning all the search queries and their output to make the answer short, but anybody can index and change the search queries and it works as expected.

Comment: In your example, `{ "title" : "amit?" }` would work fine but If you try `{ "title" : "?" }` then it won't return the result.

Answer (score 0):

Taking the following e.g. from chat as base:

> ```
> Some example titles: 
>
> title: Climate: The case of Nigerian agriculture
> title: Are you ready to change the climate?
> title: A literature review with a particular focus on the school staff
> title: What are the effects of direct public transfers on social solidarity?
> title: Community-Led Practical and/or Social Support Interventions for Adults Living at Home.
>
> If I search by only "?" then it should return the 2nd and 4th results.
> If I search by "/" then it should return only last record.
> Search by climate then 1st and 2nd results.
> Search by climate? then 1st, 2nd, and 4th results.
> ```

The solution would require to create analyzers for following cases:

1. To search for special character. I'm considering these as punctuation e.g. `/`, `?` etc.
2. To search for keyword and special char. e.g. `climate?`
3. To search for keyword. e.g. `climate`

For **case 1** we'll use [pattern tokenizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-pattern-tokenizer.html) but instead of using pattern to split we'll use pattern to extract special characters as tokens and for this we set `"group": 0` while defining the tokenizer. e.g. for text `xyz a/b pq?` tokens generated will be `/`, `?`

For **case 2** we'll create custom analyser with `filter` as `lowercase` (to make case insensitive) and `tokenizer` as `whitespace` (to retain special chars with keywords).
e.g. for text `How many?` tokens generated will be `how`, `many?`

For **case 3** we'll use `standard` analyser which is the default analyser.

Next step would be to create sub fields for `title`. `title` would be of type `text` and by default will have `standard` analyzer. This mapping property will have two sub-fields `withSplChar` of type `text` and analyzer created for **case 2** (`ci_whitespace`), `splChars` of type `text` and analyzer created for **case 1** (`splchar`)

Let's now see the above in action:

```
PUT test
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "tokenizer": {
        "splchar": {
          "type": "pattern",
          "pattern": "\\p{Punct}",
          "group": 0
        }
      },
      "analyzer": {
        "splchar": {
          "tokenizer": "splchar"
        },
        "ci_whitespace": {
          "type": "custom",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase"
          ],
          "tokenizer": "whitespace"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "title": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "withSplChar": {
            "type": "text",
            "analyzer": "ci_whitespace"
          },
          "splChars": {
            "type": "text",
            "analyzer": "splchar"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Let's now index documents as in above example:

```
POST test/_bulk
{"index":{"_id":"1"}}
{"title":"Climate: The case of Nigerian agriculture"}
{"index":{"_id":"2"}}
{"title":"Are you ready to change the climate?"}
{"index":{"_id":"3"}}
{"title":"A literature review with a particular focus on the school staff"}
{"index":{"_id":"4"}}
{"title":"What are the effects of direct public transfers on social solidarity?"}
{"index":{"_id":"5"}}
{"title":"Community-Led Practical and/or Social Support Interventions for Adults Living at Home."}
```

#### Search for `?`

```
"hits" : [
  {
    "_index" : "test",
    "_type" : "_doc",
    "_id" : "2",
    "_score" : 0.8025915,
    "_source" : {
      "title" : "Are you ready to change the climate?"
    }
  },
  {
    "_index" : "test",
    "_type" : "_doc",
    "_id" : "4",
    "_score" : 0.8025915,
    "_source" : {
      "title" : "What are the effects of direct public transfers on social solidarity?"
    }
  }
]
```

**Result:**

```
   "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "test",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "2",
        "_score" : 0.8025915,
        "_source" : {
          "title" : "Are you ready to change the climate?"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "test",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "4",
        "_score" : 0.8025915,
        "_source" : {
          "title" : "What are the effects of direct public transfers on social solidarity?"
        }
      }
    ]
```

#### Search for `climate`

```
POST test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "climate",
      "fields": ["title", "title.withSplChar", "title.splChars"]
    }
  }
}
```

**Result:**

```
"hits" : [
  {
    "_index" : "test",
    "_type" : "_doc",
    "_id" : "1",
    "_score" : 1.0341107,
    "_source" : {
      "title" : "Climate: The case of Nigerian agriculture"
    }
  },
  {
    "_index" : "test",
    "_type" : "_doc",
    "_id" : "2",
    "_score" : 0.98455274,
    "_source" : {
      "title" : "Are you ready to change the climate?"
    }
  }
]
```

#### Search for `climate?`

```
POST test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "climate\\?",
      "fields": ["title", "title.withSplChar", "title.splChars"]
    }
  }
}
```

**Result:**

```
"hits" : [
  {
    "_index" : "test",
    "_type" : "_doc",
    "_id" : "2",
    "_score" : 1.5366155,
    "_source" : {
      "title" : "Are you ready to change the climate?"
    }
  },
  {
    "_index" : "test",
    "_type" : "_doc",
    "_id" : "1",
    "_score" : 1.0341107,
    "_source" : {
      "title" : "Climate: The case of Nigerian agriculture"
    }
  },
  {
    "_index" : "test",
    "_type" : "_doc",
    "_id" : "4",
    "_score" : 0.8025915,
    "_source" : {
      "title" : "What are the effects of direct public transfers on social solidarity?"
    }
  }
]
```